Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value
Private Sub PopulateLayout(ByVal entity_id As Integer)
    Dim sSQL As String
    
    cboLayout.Clear
    
    sSQL = "PS_Layout_list @deal_only=1, @entity_id=" & entity_id
    
    rs.Open sSQL
    Do While Not rs.EOF
       cboLayout.AddItem
       cboLayout.Column(0, cboLayout.ListCount - 1) = rs("layout_id").Value
       cboLayout.Column(1, cboLayout.ListCount - 1) = rs("description").Value
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    
    If cboEntity = 4505 Then
       cboLayout = 14400  ' here is where error occurred
    End If
    cboSnapshot.SetFocus
End Sub


have a look at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-property-value-error-3802-of-2
You tried to set one of the properties of an object or control to a value outside its permissible range. Change the property value to a valid setting. For example, the MousePointer property must be set to an integer from 0 - 15 or 99.

A wild guess (as you don't tell anything about the code): cboLayout is a comboBox. With cboLayout = 14400 you want to set the value 14400 to that comboBox. The comboBox has the property MatchRequired set to True but the value 14400 was not part of the fetched recordset and therefore isn't an allowed value. This throws exactly this error.
